# Mouseover on large SVG results in high cpu usage (poor performance)

Tags: performance, svg, cpu, cpu-usage, mouseover

I am analyzing the performance of a javascript library that shows large SVG's (with a lot a elements).

The high cpu usage occurs when continuously moving the mouse over the SVG (even if it's in an empty area of the SVG)

Looking at the 'Performance monitor' in Chrome I was confused, because Chrome doesn't seem to recognize where the load comes from (see the gray area in the image, this is categorized as 'other').

I ended up opening the SVG in Chrome by itself (without any javascript) and I still get the same result.

Also when I zoom in on the svg and then repeat the same thing, the CPU load is even higher.

Setting pointer-events to 'none', doesn't make a difference.

Is there someway to optimize this? if not I would at least like to understand what is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Update]
The problem seems to be Chromium related and also dependent on the machine.

All chromium based browsers have this issue on my machine.
I've tested it on 3 other machines, 2 of which don't have the issue.
While the 3rd does.

I submitted a bug with chromium:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1235143